# linux : compare just a part of two directory names

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

Here's where I'm stuck up.
I've a old file (Fieldart_1.2.war). And I've a new file named Fieldart_1.4.war.
I just have to deploy the new one. But, before that I need to make sure I'm hitting the right file. 
Is there anyway I can compare just the first part of the two files i.e., 'Fieldart' ? like, if the first part matches, go ahead with the deployment otherwise, throw an error..

What do you guys think ?

Comment: The linked duplicate should work; there is nothing inherently special about using the dot character as extension separator.  Use the same logic for underscore and voilá.

Comment: What kind of script etc. are you using for deployment (and deciding about the correct file)?

Comment: Linux is an OS kernel. Set a context relevant to your question and you will attract better answers. Such as which scripting environment are you involved in.

Answer (score 0):

use the command find . -name "Fieldart*"